# Mobile hybrid t-shirt app, what framework/tools to use?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a mobile t-shirt app and I am just starting with mobile programming. The information is scattered and frankly I am not sure what are the best tools to use. I want to use AngularJS, and there are some directives to help with the canvas, but I am confused.

What do you think, what are the most appropriate tools to use? There will probably be a canvas as you should be able to choose a design and drop it on the t-shirt and customize the size or position further. Any help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a canvas for that.

Have all designs as separate elements (may be png images). Initially have designs somewhere in other container which a user can pick, drag and drop onto t-shirt.You can use ngDraggable for achieving that. Change the css property "position" of dropped images to "absolute" so that user can place it anywhere on t-shirt. Next, user can select t-shirt and on touchmove event change css property "transform" to "scale" based on how much he drags(captured by touchmove's event object).

If you are planning for a hybrid app, go for **Ionic Framework**, as angular comes packaged with it. Else if are planning for a better UX (user experience, while all dragging and dropping events so that the feel of the app gives a native feel), you can see **famo.us-angular Framwork.**

Comment: Thank you so much :) I would upvote but it doesn't let me. I started with Ionic and Angular, and then everywhere I read about tees designer it said canvas. Might try famo.us now. Thanks!

Comment: @ByzmoPRopagands : because you have less reputation. ;)